# Meme generator node.js discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make a meme generator but it keeps saying error at the end "}});"

Here is my code:

````
  if (msg.author == client.user){return}
  let message = msg.content.toLowerCase()
     if (message.content === "?meme") {
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        got('https://www.reddit.com/r/memes/random/.json').then(response => {
            let content = JSON.parse(response.body);
            let permalink = content[0].data.children[0].data.permalink;
            let memeUrl = `https://reddit.com${permalink}`;
            let memeImage = content[0].data.children[0].data.url;
            let memeTitle = content[0].data.children[0].data.title;
            let memeUpvotes = content[0].data.children[0].data.ups;
            let memeDownvotes = content[0].data.children[0].data.downs;
            let memeNumComments = content[0].data.children[0].data.num_comments;
            embed.setTitle(`${memeTitle}`)
            embed.setURL(`${memeUrl}`)
            embed.setImage(memeImage)
            embed.setColor('RANDOM')
            embed.setFooter(` ${memeUpvotes}  ${memeDownvotes}  ${memeNumComments}`)
            message.channel.send(embed);
        }});```
````

Answer (score 0):

Correct the last line to `})};`

I mean, this `}});` should become this `})};`

Comment: still error I used glitch for coding if that helps you